# how to extract a certain field from standard output with cut?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have this output and want to extract the IMAGE ID from it

```
$ podman image ls | grep youtube-dl
localhost/youtube-dl          latest           2d4e37c4d609  3 hours ago    205 MB
```

All I know piping this to `cut -f3` should to this but doesn't. The output is actually identical.
All examples for cut I've found tell me that a tab (which applies here I believe) is assumed as delimiter.

Can anybody kindly point me to the right direction in this? Maybe I am falsely assuming the output uses tabs. I couldn't say what else however

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* this out is **tab** delimited?
That would be quite *unusual* in a linux environment - *whitespace* delimiting is *far* more common.

Use one of the "[awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)" family of tools instead:

```
$ podman image ls | gawk '/youtube-dl/{print $3;}'
2d4e37c4d609
```

Comment: tx, that works. Never heard of those till today. Seems another field I have to explore.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. For instance, you can pipe your command output through `cut` while modifying the fiealds delimiter:

`$ podman image ls | grep grep youtube-dl | tr -s ' ' | cut -d\  -f3`

It is also possible to reveal the delimiter being used (e.g. TAB or space) by piping the output through `od` as in:

`$ podman image ls | grep grep youtube-dl | od -An -c`

Comment: `cut -d" " -f3` doesn't work unless you squeeze the whitespace first: cut does not consider _sequences_ of the delimiter. `... | tr -s '[:blank:]' | cut -d" " -f3`

Comment: You are right about having delimiter sequences; they must be removed if any. I'll update, but target the space character only, i.e., not using the entire class.

Comment: this `$ podman image ls | grep grep youtube-dl | tr -s ' ' | cut -d\  -f3` does exactly what I was looking for, thx @BrahimGaabab @glenn_jackman (just  as the `gawk` solution further up north).